# What exactly do eigenvalue and eigenvector indicate?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What exactly do eigenvalue and eigenvector indicate?

I mean what is the importance in calculating them. We all know how to calculate them but I do not know the exact importance

Comment: Absent a specific statistical context, this is purely a mathematical question, and probably belongs on math.SE.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html which has a sentence about that.

Comment: As usual, [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Principal_components_analysis) is a good place to start. In case you overlooked it in the previous sentence, here is the link again: [**link**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Principal_components_analysis). The link above will take you directly to applications of eigenvectors in PCA, which is what you specifically asked about. And [**the rest of that page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) contains several other applications.

Comment: Both answers given so far should be comments. I'm flagging both.

Answer (score 2):

Think of a matrix as an *operator* - one that operates on vectors, and returns another vector, which is a rotated, skewed and stretched copy of the original. Now, if we ignore length changes, some of the vectors will be left unchanged by this matrix, and retain their overall direction (though not their length): **It is these vectors we call the eigenvectors of the matrix**, and the factor by which their magnitude changes is called their eigenvalue.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me why eigenvalues are used in PCA. Specifically why and how does it explain the variance of the components

Comment: @Shashank - no. If you want to ask about a totally unrelated question, please open a new question on the topic.

Comment: Done. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707855/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-in-pca

Comment: @nbubis Did you mean to say: It is these vectors we call the **eigenvectors** of the matrix.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar - Thanks, fixed.