# EigenValues and EigenVectors in PCA?

Tags: linear-algebra

can you please tell me why eigenvalues are used in PCA. Specifically why and how does it explain the variance of the components

Answer (score 0):

I believe that PCA is one of the most well-suited applications of eigenvector/eigenvalues.

- Raw data can possibly be coupled(*made complex*) with *principal component*.
- Some coupling can be thought of linear transformations.
- [Eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be used to decouple linear transformation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23312/what-is-the-importance-of-eigenvalues-eigenvectors?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- Calculate the accuracy of mapping to the new set of data.
- Let's package it nicely with a name called PCA.

I found a [good youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgakZw6K1QQ) that explain PCA well.

To explain [coupling](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-if-two-equations-are-coupled-or-uncoupled), think of two variables, area,$A$ and perimeter,$P$ of a rectangle. We know that $A = width * height$ and $P = 2(width+height)$. Thus we can say that $A$ and $p$ is coupled with $width$ and $height$ of the rectangle, changing $A$ will also change $p$ because of the change of $width$ and $height$. Though the example I given is not linear, you can get the idea.